# How to reload page in Ember or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ember.js

How can i force a reload instead of a transition in Ember.Route

For example inside this function:

`File: play_route.js`

```
actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition, route) {
        transition.abort();
        transition.refresh();
        // maybe
        // window.location.href = route;
    }
}
```

How can i force a reload inside Ember.Controller

For example inside this function:

`File: play_controller.js`

```
actions: {
    reloadPage: function() {
        // reload baby
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `window.location.reload()`?

Comment: What is the compatibility with Ember?

Comment: It is pure JavaScript. Does ember disable pure JavaScript?

Comment: What about my second question, which is reloading to a specific Ember.Route instead of a transition?

Comment: Why are you needing to reload the page?

Comment: @kingpin2k It's a workaround for Phaser game framework. I need to properly destroy it. Also in my solution, `transition.targetName` doesn't work for home page, it returns `index` which is a 404. Do you have an ultimate solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

This should do the trick:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: What about a specific route within Ember.route, instead of a transition to that route, i need a reload to that route.

Comment: If you know the route then just do `window.location.href = route`

Answer (score 1):

So according to you guys I've solved my both problems as follows,
acknowledge if this is the proper way to do this.

In controller i refresh the page:

`window.location.reload(true);`

In route i transition to specific route:

```
actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition, route) {
        transition.abort();

        window.location.href = '/' + transition.targetName;
    }
}
```

Comment: this may be correct in older versions but currently `transition.targetName` is not the path. So if you had nested routes like `store/info` the `targetName` would be `store.info`